# Why do I get a 401 error "API Key missing" when calling openweathermap API?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, openweathermap

I attempted to make a python weather report with OpenWeatherMap.org. However, python keeps giving me an error about the **API key**. It says it is missing.

```
import requests

r = requests.get("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid={API key}")
print(r.status_code)
```

The output is **401**. I tried putting my API key in but it still didn't work. And **what is this API Key** anyways?

Comment: Well, you're not using an f-string. So, you should do that by placing the letter `f` before your URL. You would need your own API key from here: https://home.openweathermap.org/users/sign_up to be able to access their API.

Comment: That `{API key}` from the [openweathermap docs](https://openweathermap.org/appid#example) is meant to be a placeholder. You need to put your actual API key in there ("*you can always find it on your account page under the "API key" tab*").

Comment: Thank you! I cannot mark your answers if you put them in the comments.

Comment: [link](https://replit.com/@EmmaGao8/API-Weather-Report#main.py)

Comment: I made my comment into an answer. Also, I suggest removing the link to your code that uses your actual API key. You should not be sharing your API keys or tokens publicly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `{API key}` is meant to be a placeholder for your *actual* API key which you can get from your openweathermap account page (which also means you will need to sign-up for an account first). It should be something like this:

```
appid='12345678901234567890123456789012'
r = requests.get(f'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid={appid}')
```

Printing [other parts of the Response object](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Response) would have given you more information:

```
In [2]: r = requests.get("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid={API key}")

In [3]: r.status_code
Out[3]: 401

In [6]: r.content
Out[6]: b'{"cod":401, "message": "Invalid API key. Please see http://openweathermap.org/faq#error401 for more info."}'
```

The page at http://openweathermap.org/faq#error401 would explain that you needed to provide a valid API key, and would lead you to their [docs on how to use API keys](https://openweathermap.org/appid#example):

> #### Example on how to make an API call using your API key
>
> ---
>
> API call
>
> ```
> http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=524901&appid={API
> key}
> ```
>
> Parameters
>
> `appid`   required
> Your unique API key (you can always find it on
> your account page under the ["API key"
> tab](https://home.openweathermap.org/api_keys))